# store data & metadata in DOM or JS object ? which is performant?

Tags: javascript, dom, object, performance

I've a form with elements, I need to create a fieldset/sub forms with more elements for each of the main form element, dynamically based on a dropdown value. I need to take care of showing / hiding the sub form when moving between the sub forms of the form elements, while retaining the values in the sub forms.

Which method you think is performant ?

Have 1 sub form/fieldset in the DOM and maintain a master JS object (like JSON's name:value pairs) internally in JS, which will have the information of the form elements, data & metadata of its sub form elements
When submitting, simply send the stringified JS object to server.

This method involves creating & deleting DOM elements everytime when one needs to add a new fieldset or edit the fieldset (which the user would think is already created).

Or

Create clones of the fieldsets in the DOM and do display:none/block whenever required. The metadata will be stored as attrs on the sub form elements and data will be in the DOM itself. 
Before submitting, loop through the sub form elements (using selectors) in the fieldsets of the main form elements, build a similar JS object, stringify and send to server.

This method involves settings attrs on the DOM elements, doing display:none/block as required and a final loop just before submitting to form the master JS object.

Screenshot : [image: Sub form & dom showing attrs]

I'm not sure how to use jsperf.com to understand the performance differences between the above 2 methods.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Perhaps you could illustrate what the form looks like? Using fiddle or jsbin.

Comment: Which one is easier? Does it have actual performance problems? Will there be a non-JS version, and how will that look?

Comment: There wont be a no-js version. To be frank, I dont see a visible difference in loading speeds or such thing. Just was wondering if anyone knows on top of their mind about performance between DOM & JS objects.